# Pyomo: reading a three dimensional parameter from a .dat file

Tags: python, pyomo, ampl

When reading AMPL type .dat files in Pyomo, I encounter a problem dealing with two- and three-dimensional parameters.
Following is a MWE:

The Pyomo file is:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename="lp_test.dat")

mod         = ConcreteModel()
mod.T       = Set(initialize = data["T"])
mod.I       = Set(initialize = data["I"])
mod.J       = Set(mod.T, initialize = data["J"])
mod.TJ      = Set(dimen =2, initialize = data["TJ"])

mod.V0      = Param(mod.I,              initialize = data["V0"])
mod.VMAX    = Param(mod.I,              initialize = data["VMAX"])
mod.QMAX    = Param(mod.I,              initialize = data["QMAX"])
mod.RHO     = Param(mod.I,              initialize = data["RHO"])
mod.A_1     = Param(mod.I, mod.T,       initialize = data["A1"])
mod.A_2     = Param(mod.I, mod.T,       initialize = data["A2"])
mod.B       = Param(mod.I, mod.TJ,      initialize = data["B"])
```

And the .dat file is:

```
set T   := 1 2      ; 
set I   := 1 2 3    ; 
set J[1]:= 1        ; 
set J[2]:= 1 2      ; 
set TJ  := (1,1) (2,1) (2,2);

param: VMAX  QMAX   RHO  V0:=
1      500   100    0.8  50
2      400   140    0.8  40
3      500   100    0.8  50;


param A1:  1   2:=
1        0.5  0.5
2        0.3  0.18
3        0.15 0.25;


param A2:=
[1,*] 1 0.5  2 0.5
[2,*] 1 0.3  2 0.18
[3,*] 1 0.15 2 0.25;

param B := 
[*,1,1] 1 10  2 12  3 10     
[*,2,1] 1  8  2 6   3  4   
[*,2,2] 1  7  2 5   3  2 ;
```

One dimensional parameters VMAX, QMAX, RHO and V0 are properly load. 2-Dimensional parameter A1 is also properly load, but not A2, which is equivalent to A1 in AMPL format, and according to the Pyomo book, it can be defined in this way.
Parameter B is not read.

The following error appears for A2 and B:

```
"Index '1' is not valid for indexed component 'A_2'"
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I'm guessing the problem is that you are actually building a ConcreteModel and just using `initialize` statements.  Typically, when using a DataPortal, most people build an AbstractModel.  You are kinda mixing 2 worlds here.  I'm betting if you switch to Abstract and use the DataPortal.build_instance() it will know what to do internally where the initialize command does not know the nuance of the .dat file

Comment: Thank you @AirSquid for your input. Indeed when I switch to Abstract Model, the error disappears. However, I noticed that the initialization instruction (the way I am using it here) still misinterprets the A2 parameter. I guess the best way is to build the instance as you suggest.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know use that method of pulling in data with the template.  Seems a bit sketchy, and the way you are doing A1 is clearer and easier.  I'd just go with that...